# Leaflet Routing Machine won't read waypoints from variable TypeError: t is null

Tags: leaflet, routing

I am trying to add waypoints from a variable to a leaflet map.  The resulting variable split_route1 is formatted correctly and when I hard-code the waypoints from the console log results, the waypoints render fine.  When I try to use the var splitroute1 I get an error: TypeError: t is null (leaflet.js (line 6, col 17396))

```
 function splitroute(route1){

 split_route1 = '';

 for (x = 0; x < route1.length  ; x++) { 

            split_route1 +='L.latLng(' +      route1[x].ordered_locs.displayLatLng.lat + ',' + route1[x].ordered_locs.displayLatLng.lng + '),'
    }
console.log(split_route1)
L.Routing.control({
   waypoints:   [  

          split_route1

    ],
    routeWhileDragging: true
}).addTo(map2);

     }
```

Comment: You might want to use the uncompressed leaflet.js so you can see what the error really is?

Answer (score 1):

I'd look here:

```
+= 'L.latLng('`
```

What is split_route meant to be? A multi-point array? Can you just construct this as an array and pass this in as waypoints?

```
var split_route = [];

for (x = 0; x < route1.length  ; x++) { 
    var coords = []; 
    coords.push(route1[x].ordered_locs.displayLatLng.lat, route1[x].ordered_locs.displayLatLng.lng);
    split_route.push(coords);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but your answer gave the same error.  The console log of split_route1 is 

L.latLng(43.517533,-79.697975),L.latLng(43.541817,-79.740245),L.latLng(43.547941,-79.740029),L.latLng(43.565396,-79.765799),L.latLng(43.517533,-79.697975),

When I cut and paste the console log as waypoints the map renders just fine.  When I use the variable I get the error.

Comment: skip L.latLng(), instead try just pushing these as raw coords. I've edited my answer